# Split string in Lua?

Tags: string, lua

I need to do a simple split of a string, but there doesn't seem to be a function for this, and the manual way I tested didn't seem to work. How would I do it?

Comment: Please see [Splitting Strings](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin)

Comment: On what delimiter do you want to split it?

Answer (score 178):

Here is my really simple solution. Use the `gmatch()` function to capture strings which contain at least **one** character of **anything** other than the desired separator. The separator is **any** whitespace (`%s` in Lua) by default:

```
function mysplit (inputstr, sep)
        if sep == nil then
                sep = "%s"
        end
        local t={}
        for str in string.gmatch(inputstr, "([^"..sep.."]+)") do
                table.insert(t, str)
        end
        return t
end
```

Comment: Wow, the first answer in this whole question that actually has a function that returns a table. Note though, that t and i need the "local" modifier, as it is you're overwriting globals. :)

Comment: This worked. It's just for single character delimiters. To split by strings, such as XML tags, change the match pattern to "(.-)("..sep..")" instead. Note: If the string ends with sep, the last match will fail. Append a newline or any character to the end of the input string to fix this.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: The fix for the last match is done by appending the delimiter to the end of the input string.

Comment: As others have pointed out, you can simplify this by using table.insert(t,str) instead of t[i] = str and then you don't need i=1 or i = i +1

Comment: Doesn't work if string contains empty values, eg. `'foo,,bar'`. You get `{'foo','bar'}` instead of `{'foo', '', 'bar'}`

Comment: That's right. The next version will work in that case:  `function split(inputstr, sep) sep=sep or '%s' local t={}  for field,s in string.gmatch(inputstr, "([^"..sep.."]*)("..sep.."?)") do table.insert(t,field)  if s=="" then return t end end end`

Comment: You don't need the capture group and you can even further simplify matters by using `inputstr:gmatch`

Comment: This fails if the string contains #, {, or } characters

Comment: Can this be adapted if the input string contains the *escaped* separator? For example, we want to split file names separated by spaces to iterate over them in a for loop. This is a failing attempt with three files, one of them containing spaces which were escaped: `mysplit("1.mp4 2.mp4 3\\ with\\ spaces.mp4", " ")`. How do I get those three file names as a table?

Answer (score 43):

If you are splitting a string in Lua, you should try the string.gmatch() or string.sub() methods.  Use the string.sub() method if you know the index you wish to split the string at, or use the string.gmatch() if you will parse the string to find the location to split the string at.

Example using string.gmatch() from [Lua 5.1 Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.gmatch):

```
 t = {}
 s = "from=world, to=Lua"
 for k, v in string.gmatch(s, "(%w+)=(%w+)") do
   t[k] = v
 end
```

Comment: I "borrowed" an implementation from that lua-users page thanks anyway

Answer (score 37):

If you just want to iterate over the tokens, this is pretty neat:

```
line = "one, two and 3!"

for token in string.gmatch(line, "[^%s]+") do
   print(token)
end
```

Output:

> one,
>
> two
>
> and
>
> 3!

Short explanation: the "[^%s]+" pattern matches to every non-empty string in between space characters.

Comment: The pattern `%S` is equal to the one you mentioned, as `%S` is the negation of `%s`, like `%D` is the negation of `%d`.

Additionally, `%w` is equal to `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (other characters might be supported depending on your locale).

Answer (score 19):

Just as `string.gmatch` will find *patterns* in a string, this function will find the things *between* patterns:

```
function string:split(pat)
  pat = pat or '%s+'
  local st, g = 1, self:gmatch("()("..pat..")")
  local function getter(segs, seps, sep, cap1, ...)
    st = sep and seps + #sep
    return self:sub(segs, (seps or 0) - 1), cap1 or sep, ...
  end
  return function() if st then return getter(st, g()) end end
end
```

By default it returns whatever is separated by whitespace.

Comment: +1. Note to any other Lua beginners: this returns an iterator, and 'between patterns' includes the beginning and end of the string. (As a newbie I had to try it to figure these things out.)

Answer (score 15):

Here is the function:

```
function split(pString, pPattern)
   local Table = {}  -- NOTE: use {n = 0} in Lua-5.0
   local fpat = "(.-)" .. pPattern
   local last_end = 1
   local s, e, cap = pString:find(fpat, 1)
   while s do
      if s ~= 1 or cap ~= "" then
     table.insert(Table,cap)
      end
      last_end = e+1
      s, e, cap = pString:find(fpat, last_end)
   end
   if last_end <= #pString then
      cap = pString:sub(last_end)
      table.insert(Table, cap)
   end
   return Table
end
```

Call it like:

```
list=split(string_to_split,pattern_to_match)
```

e.g.:

```
list=split("1:2:3:4","\:")
```

For more go here:
http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin

Answer (score 10):

Because there are more than one way to skin a cat, here's my approach:

**Code**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua

local content = [=[
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
]=]

local function split(str, sep)
   local result = {}
   local regex = ("([^%s]+)"):format(sep)
   for each in str:gmatch(regex) do
      table.insert(result, each)
   end
   return result
end

local lines = split(content, "\n")
for _,line in ipairs(lines) do
   print(line)
end
```

**Output**:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.`

**Explanation**:

The `gmatch` function works as an iterator, it fetches all the strings that match `regex`. The `regex` takes all characters until it finds a separator.

Answer (score 9):

A lot of these answers only accept single-character separators, or don't deal with edge cases well (e.g. empty separators), so I thought I would provide a more definitive solution.

Here are two functions, `gsplit` and `split`, adapted from the [code](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/ELUA/browse/master/engines/LuaCommon/lualib/mw.text.lua;1e408e20e800c32dfcd9bc0d55491adb631d191c$210) in the [Scribunto MediaWiki extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto), which is used on wikis like Wikipedia. The code is licenced under the [GPL v2](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/ELUA/browse/master/COPYING). I have changed the variable names and added comments to make the code a bit easier to understand, and I have also changed the code to use regular Lua string patterns instead of Scribunto's patterns for Unicode strings. The original code has test cases [here](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/ELUA/browse/master/tests/engines/LuaCommon/TextLibraryTests.lua;1e408e20e800c32dfcd9bc0d55491adb631d191c$160).

```
-- gsplit: iterate over substrings in a string separated by a pattern
-- 
-- Parameters:
-- text (string)    - the string to iterate over
-- pattern (string) - the separator pattern
-- plain (boolean)  - if true (or truthy), pattern is interpreted as a plain
--                    string, not a Lua pattern
-- 
-- Returns: iterator
--
-- Usage:
-- for substr in gsplit(text, pattern, plain) do
--   doSomething(substr)
-- end
local function gsplit(text, pattern, plain)
  local splitStart, length = 1, #text
  return function ()
    if splitStart then
      local sepStart, sepEnd = string.find(text, pattern, splitStart, plain)
      local ret
      if not sepStart then
        ret = string.sub(text, splitStart)
        splitStart = nil
      elseif sepEnd < sepStart then
        -- Empty separator!
        ret = string.sub(text, splitStart, sepStart)
        if sepStart < length then
          splitStart = sepStart + 1
        else
          splitStart = nil
        end
      else
        ret = sepStart > splitStart and string.sub(text, splitStart, sepStart - 1) or ''
        splitStart = sepEnd + 1
      end
      return ret
    end
  end
end

-- split: split a string into substrings separated by a pattern.
-- 
-- Parameters:
-- text (string)    - the string to iterate over
-- pattern (string) - the separator pattern
-- plain (boolean)  - if true (or truthy), pattern is interpreted as a plain
--                    string, not a Lua pattern
-- 
-- Returns: table (a sequence table containing the substrings)
local function split(text, pattern, plain)
  local ret = {}
  for match in gsplit(text, pattern, plain) do
    table.insert(ret, match)
  end
  return ret
end
```

Some examples of the `split` function in use:

```
local function printSequence(t)
  print(unpack(t))
end

printSequence(split('foo, bar,baz', ',%s*'))       -- foo     bar     baz
printSequence(split('foo, bar,baz', ',%s*', true)) -- foo, bar,baz
printSequence(split('foo', ''))                    -- f       o       o
```

Comment: the line `ret = sepStart > splitStart and string.sub(text, splitStart, sepStart - 1) or ''` can be simplified to just `ret = string.sub(text, splitStart, sepStart - 1)`?

Comment: @pynexj I think you are correct about this. I thought this would break if `sepStart` is zero, as `string.sub(text, splitStart, -1)` will return the substring from splitStart to the end of the string, not the empty string. However, `string.find` will never return zero, so this case will never occur. If I have some time I will port over the unit tests to make sure everything works, and make the change.

Answer (score 7):

I like this short solution

```
function split(s, delimiter)
    result = {};
    for match in (s..delimiter):gmatch("(.-)"..delimiter) do
        table.insert(result, match);
    end
    return result;
end
```

Comment: This is my favorite, since it's so short and simple.

I don't quite understand what happens, could someone explain to me?

Comment: This fails when using dot as delimiter (or potentially any other pattern magic character)

Answer (score 6):

You can use this method:

```
function string:split(delimiter)
  local result = { }
  local from  = 1
  local delim_from, delim_to = string.find( self, delimiter, from  )
  while delim_from do
    table.insert( result, string.sub( self, from , delim_from-1 ) )
    from  = delim_to + 1
    delim_from, delim_to = string.find( self, delimiter, from  )
  end
  table.insert( result, string.sub( self, from  ) )
  return result
end

delimiter = string.split(stringtodelimite,pattern)
```

Answer (score 6):

a way not seen in others

```
function str_split(str, sep)
    if sep == nil then
        sep = '%s'
    end 

    local res = {}
    local func = function(w)
        table.insert(res, w)
    end 

    string.gsub(str, '[^'..sep..']+', func)
    return res 
end
```

Comment: @MattSephton i use a func instead of loop

Answer (score 6):

You could use [penlight library](https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight). This has a function for splitting string using delimiter which outputs list.

It has implemented many of the function that we may need while programming and missing in Lua.

Here is the sample for using it.

```
> 
> stringx = require "pl.stringx"
> 
> str = "welcome to the world of lua"
> 
> arr = stringx.split(str, " ")
> 
> arr
{welcome,to,the,world,of,lua}
>
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply sitting on a delimiter

```
local str = 'one,two'
local regxEverythingExceptComma = '([^,]+)'
for x in string.gmatch(str, regxEverythingExceptComma) do
    print(x)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the above examples to craft my own function. But the missing piece for me was automatically escaping magic characters.

Here is my contribution:

```
function split(text, delim)
    -- returns an array of fields based on text and delimiter (one character only)
    local result = {}
    local magic = "().%+-*?[]^$"

    if delim == nil then
        delim = "%s"
    elseif string.find(delim, magic, 1, true) then
        -- escape magic
        delim = "%"..delim
    end

    local pattern = "[^"..delim.."]+"
    for w in string.gmatch(text, pattern) do
        table.insert(result, w)
    end
    return result
end
```

Comment: This was my big issue too. This works great with magic characters, nice one

Comment: might be stupid, but what are 'magic characters'?

Answer (score 3):

Super late to this question, but in case anyone wants a version that handles the amount of splits you want to get.....

```lua
-- Split a string into a table using a delimiter and a limit
string.split = function(str, pat, limit)
  local t = {}
  local fpat = "(.-)" .. pat
  local last_end = 1
  local s, e, cap = str:find(fpat, 1)
  while s do
    if s ~= 1 or cap ~= "" then
      table.insert(t, cap)
    end

    last_end = e+1
    s, e, cap = str:find(fpat, last_end)

    if limit ~= nil and limit <= #t then
      break
    end
  end

  if last_end <= #str then
    cap = str:sub(last_end)
    table.insert(t, cap)
  end

  return t
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For those coming from the exercice 10.1 of the "Programming in Lua" book, it seems clear that we could not use notion explained later in the book (iterator) and that the function should take more than a single char seperator.

The `split()` is a trick to get pattern to match what is *not* wanted (the split) and return an empty table on empty string. The return of `plainSplit()` is more like the split in other language.

```lua
magic = "([%%%.%(%)%+%*%?%[%]%^%$])"

function split(str, sep, plain)
    if plain then sep = string.gsub(sep, magic, "%%%1") end
    
    local N = '\255'
    str = N..str..N
    str = string.gsub(str, sep, N..N)

    local result = {}
    for word in string.gmatch(str, N.."(.-)"..N) do
        if word ~= "" then
            table.insert(result, word)
        end
    end
    return result
end


function plainSplit(str, sep)
    sep = string.gsub(sep, magic, "%%%1")

    local result = {}
    local start = 0
    repeat
        start = start + 1

        local from, to = string.find(str, sep, start)
        from = from and from-1
        
        local word = string.sub(str, start, from, true)
        table.insert(result, word)

        start = to
    until start == nil

    return result
end


function tableToString(t)
    local ret = "{"
    for _, word in ipairs(t) do
        ret = ret .. '"' .. word .. '", '
    end
    ret = string.sub(ret, 1, -3)
    ret = ret .. "}"

    return #ret > 1 and ret or "{}"
end

function runSplit(func, title, str, sep, plain)
    print("\n" .. title)
    print("str: '"..str.."'")
    print("sep: '"..sep.."'")
    local t = func(str, sep, plain)
    print("-- t = " .. tableToString(t))
end



print("\n\n\n=== Pattern split ===")
runSplit(split, "Exercice 10.1", "a whole new world", " ")
runSplit(split, "With trailing seperator", "  a  whole   new world  ", " ")
runSplit(split, "A word seperator", "a whole new world", " whole ")
runSplit(split, "Pattern seperator", "a1whole2new3world", "%d")
runSplit(split, "Magic characters as plain seperator", "a$.%whole$.%new$.%world", "$.%", true)
runSplit(split, "Control seperator", "a\0whole\1new\2world", "%c")
runSplit(split, "ISO Time", "2020-07-10T15:00:00.000", "[T:%-%.]")

runSplit(split, " === [Fails] with \\255 ===", "a\255whole\0new\0world", "\0", true)

runSplit(split, "How does your function handle empty string?", "", " ")



print("\n\n\n=== Plain split ===")
runSplit(plainSplit, "Exercice 10.1", "a whole new world", " ")
runSplit(plainSplit, "With trailing seperator", "  a  whole   new world  ", " ")
runSplit(plainSplit, "A word seperator", "a whole new world", " whole ")
runSplit(plainSplit, "Magic characters as plain seperator", "a$.%whole$.%new$.%world", "$.%")

runSplit(plainSplit, "How does your function handle empty string?", "", " ")
```

output

```bash
=== Pattern split ===

Exercice 10.1
str: 'a whole new world'
sep: ' '
-- t = {"a", "whole", "new", "world"}

With trailing seperator
str: '  a  whole   new world  '
sep: ' '
-- t = {"a", "whole", "new", "world"}

A word seperator
str: 'a whole new world'
sep: ' whole '
-- t = {"a", "new world"}

Pattern seperator
str: 'a1whole2new3world'
sep: '%d'
-- t = {"a", "whole", "new", "world"}

Magic characters as plain seperator
str: 'a$.%whole$.%new$.%world'
sep: '$.%'
-- t = {"a", "whole", "new", "world"}

Control seperator
str: 'awholenewworld'
sep: '%c'
-- t = {"a", "whole", "new", "world"}

ISO Time
str: '2020-07-10T15:00:00.000'
sep: '[T:%-%.]'
-- t = {"2020", "07", "10", "15", "00", "00", "000"}

 === [Fails] with \255 ===
str: 'a�wholenewworld'
sep: ''
-- t = {"a"}

How does your function handle empty string?
str: ''
sep: ' '
-- t = {}



=== Plain split ===

Exercice 10.1
str: 'a whole new world'
sep: ' '
-- t = {"a", "whole", "new", "world"}

With trailing seperator
str: '  a  whole   new world  '
sep: ' '
-- t = {"", "", "a", "", "whole", "", "", "new", "world", "", ""}

A word seperator
str: 'a whole new world'
sep: ' whole '
-- t = {"a", "new world"}

Magic characters as plain seperator
str: 'a$.%whole$.%new$.%world'
sep: '$.%'
-- t = {"a", "whole", "new", "world"}

How does your function handle empty string?
str: ''
sep: ' '
-- t = {""}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that many of the other answers had edge cases which failed (eg. when given string contains `#`, `{` or `}` characters, or when given a delimiter character like `%` which require escaping).  Here is the implementation that I went with instead:

```
local function newsplit(delimiter, str)
    assert(type(delimiter) == "string")
    assert(#delimiter > 0, "Must provide non empty delimiter")

    -- Add escape characters if delimiter requires it
    delimiter = delimiter:gsub("[%(%)%.%%%+%-%*%?%[%]%^%$]", "%%%0")

    local start_index = 1
    local result = {}

    while true do
       local delimiter_index, _ = str:find(delimiter, start_index)

       if delimiter_index == nil then
          table.insert(result, str:sub(start_index))
          break
       end

       table.insert(result, str:sub(start_index, delimiter_index - 1))

       start_index = delimiter_index + 1
    end

    return result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an example (`unexpandTabs`) at the end of the **Replacements** section of [Programming in Lua, 4th Ed.](https://www.lua.org/pil/), Chapter 10, that uses the [`SOH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#SOH) character (`\1`) to mark tab columns for later processing. I thought that was a neat idea, so I adapted it to the "match everything except a delimiter character" ideas that many of the answers here use. By preprocessing the input string to replace all matches with `\1`, we can support arbitrary delimiter *patterns*, which is something only some answers do, e.g. @norman-ramsey's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1647577/12162258).

I also included an `exclude_empty` parameter with default behavior just for fun.

Obviously this will produce bad output if the input string contains `\1`, but that seems extremely unlikely in any case outside of specialized protocol exchanges.

```lua
function string:split(pat, exclude_empty)
  pat = pat or "%s+"
  self = self:gsub(pat, "\1")
  local res = {}
  for match in self:gmatch("([^\1]" .. (exclude_empty and "+" or "*") .. ")") do
    res[#res + 1] = match
  end
  return res
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest/simplest solution yet? For splitting on whitespace, that is.

```lua
function(argstr)
  local args = {}
  for v in string.gmatch(argstr, "%S+") do
    table.insert(args, v)
  end
  return args
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to split a string to two strings in given position:

```
str1 = "helloworld"
str2 = ""
index = 5
str1, str2 = string.sub(str1, 1, index), string.sub(str1, index+1, -1)
print (str1, str2) -- hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

this function extends string with split function 'python like'.

```
-- string functions utilities
string.split=function(self,sep,limit)
    if sep==nil then
        sep=" "
    end
    local _table = {}
    local _string = ''
    local x = 0 -- separation counter
    for i=1,#self do
        local char=string.sub(self,i,i) -- get character 'i' in string
        if limit==nil then
            -- unlimited separations
            if char == sep then
                -- separation found, insert string in table and 'reset' string to store next world
                table.insert(_table,_string)
                _string=""
            else
                _string = _string .. char -- store no separation character to store later
                if i==#self then
                    -- last character in string, just add its remain to table
                    table.insert(_table,_string)
                end
            end 
        elseif type(limit)=="number" then
            -- limited separations
            if char == sep then
                -- separation character found
                x=x+1 -- increment separator count
                if x<=limit then
                    -- while separator count <= limit, add _string to _table, and reset _string to next world
                    table.insert(_table,_string)
                    _string="" 
                else
                    -- separator counter limit pass, now just concat chars to the last string
                    _string = _string .. sep
                end
            else
                -- no char seprator, concat char to string and insert in table if last char
                _string = _string .. char
                if i==#self then
                    table.insert(_table,_string)
                end
            end
        end

    end
    -- return splitted table
    return _table
end
```

usage:

```
msg='my favorite string'
msg=msg:split(' ',1)
```

this will result in table {'my','favorite string'} as expected!

Answer (score -1):

Here is a routine that works in Lua 4.0, returning a table **t** of the substrings in **inputstr** delimited by **sep**:

```
function string_split(inputstr, sep)
    local inputstr = inputstr .. sep
    local idx, inc, t = 0, 1, {}
    local idx_prev, substr
    repeat 
        idx_prev = idx
        inputstr = strsub(inputstr, idx + 1, -1)    -- chop off the beginning of the string containing the match last found by strfind (or initially, nothing); keep the rest (or initially, all)
        idx = strfind(inputstr, sep)                -- find the 0-based r_index of the first occurrence of separator 
        if idx == nil then break end                -- quit if nothing's found
        substr = strsub(inputstr, 0, idx)           -- extract the substring occurring before the separator (i.e., data field before the next delimiter)
        substr = gsub(substr, "[%c" .. sep .. " ]", "") -- eliminate control characters, separator and spaces
        t[inc] = substr             -- store the substring (i.e., data field)
        inc = inc + 1               -- iterate to next
    until idx == nil
    return t
end
```

This simple test

```
inputstr = "the brown lazy fox jumped over the fat grey hen ... or something."
sep = " " 
t = {}
t = string_split(inputstr,sep)
for i=1,15 do
    print(i, t[i])
end
```

Yields:

```
--> t[1]=the
--> t[2]=brown
--> t[3]=lazy
--> t[4]=fox
--> t[5]=jumped
--> t[6]=over
--> t[7]=the
--> t[8]=fat
--> t[9]=grey
--> t[10]=hen
--> t[11]=...
--> t[12]=or
--> t[13]=something.
```

Answer (score -3):

Depending on the use case, this could be useful.  It cuts all text either side of the flags:

```
b = "This is a string used for testing"

--Removes unwanted text
c = (b:match("a([^/]+)used"))

print (c)
```

Output:

```
string
```

Comment: I dont see any relation to the question.