# lua split into words

Tags: string, lua

I have a string in lua.

It's a bunch of [a-zA-Z0-9]+ separated by a number (1 or more) spaces.

How do I take the string and split it into a table of strings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string in lua?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426954/split-string-in-lua)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
s = "foo bar 123"
words = {}
for word in s:gmatch("%w+") do table.insert(words, word) end
```

Comment: reference manual gnome says: `%w` represents all alphanumeric characters.

Comment: %w not correct for me, it includes an alphanumeric character for spliting. e.g "FAULT_CODE FAULTCODE" return 3 values

Comment: @PankajRawat, well the original question specified `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` which would not include `_`. You'd probably want to use the answer provided by @lhf.

Answer (score 46):

```
s="How do I take the string and split it into a table of strings?"
for w in s:gmatch("%S+") do print(w) end
```

Comment: reference manual gnome says: `%S` represents all non-space characters.

Comment: The accepted answer (ponzao) is ok with the specification in the question, but the reason to prefer lhf's answer is that if you have 8-bit or multibyte text (everything non-ascii), you can still split correctly on only spaces using this method.

Comment: @u0b34a0f6ae So, for example, it would work with UTF-8 encoding. : ]]] (but not with some Unicode special whitespaces that use longer code points)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to split words and merge them:

```
function mergeStr (strA, strB)
  local tablA, tablB = {}, {}
  for word in strA:gmatch("%S+") do
    table.insert (tablA, word)
  end
  for word in strB:gmatch("%S+") do
    table.insert (tablB, word)
  end
  return tablA[1] .. ' ' .. tablB[3] .. ' ' .. tablA[5]
end

print (mergeStr ("Lua is a programming language", "I love coding"))
-- "Lua coding language"
```