# How do I do user inputs on the same line in Lua?

Tags: input, io, lua

Here is my code:

```
while true do
    opr = io.read() txt = io.read()
    if opr == "print" then
        print(txt)
    else
        print("wat")
    end
end
```

What I'm trying to do is make it where you type `print` and then whatever you want like this:

```
print text
```

And it'll print `text` but I can't seem to do it on the same line without having to press enter after typing `print`.  I always end up having to write it like:

```
print
text
```

If anyone knows how I can fix this please answer.

Comment: Sorry, I understood  your question incorrectly the first time. Is it OK to assume that the two words are always in the same line or do you want something that works both for words in the same line and for words on separate lines?

Comment: Uhh...  I want it where when you type "print stuff" it prints "stuff".  I'm trying to make a joke "programming language" for a project.  I want print to let it know it's printing something and it to print the word after print.  You would type "print whatever" and press enter instead of typing "print" enter "whatever" enter.

Comment: Can assume that in the end each line will have a single command and each command will be written in a single line?

Comment: Why not simply read whole string (opr + txt) and then split it into a command and its parameters (if any) ?

Comment: This question might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779700/lua-split-into-words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When called without arguments, `io.read()` reads a whole line. You could read the line and get the words using pattern matching:

```
input = io.read()
opr, txt = input:match("(%S+)%s+(%S+)")
```

---

The above code assumes that there is just one word for `opr` and one word for `txt`. If there might be zero or more `txt`, try this:

```
while true do
    local input = io.read()
    local i, j = input:find("%S+")
    local opr = input:sub(i, j)
    local others = input:sub(j + 1)
    local t = {}
    for s in others:gmatch("%S+") do
        table.insert(t, s)
    end
    if opr == "print" then
        print(table.unpack(t))
    else
        print("wat")
    end
end
```

Comment: Some commands may have zero parameters or more than one parameter

Comment: I've encountered only one error...  It only prints the first word (ex. print this that and it prints this) If you can help that'd be great!

Comment: I also cannot do any elseif's after the original if.

Comment: "attempt to call field 'unpack' (a nil value)" error message.

Comment: @Prince - replace `table.unpack` with `unpack`

Answer (score 1):

Well, that is because io.read() nactually reads an entire line.
What you have to do is read a line:

```
command = op.read()
```

and then analyze the string.
For what you want to do, the best is probably to iterate the string looking for spaces to separate each word and save it into a table. Then you can pretty much do with it whatever you want.
You can also interpret the command on the fly while iterating:

```
Read in the first word;
if it is "print" then read in the rest of the line and print it;
if it is "foo" read in the next 3 words as aprameters and call bar();
```

etc.

For now I am leaving the implementation for to you. If you need help with that leave a comment.