# how can i get all the text that comes after a words

Tags: lua

What I have so far:

```
local msg = "hello hi hey"
local words = {}
for word in msg:gmatch("%S+") do
    table.insert(words, word)
end
-- splits msg by every blank space and drops it in words
```

I want get rid of the first word in msg, and save the rest as a variable. I figured out I could do `table.remove(words, 1)` to get rid of the first word, but how can I save the rest as a variable?

Comment: Duplicated, you can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779700/lua-split-into-words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the answer from [lua split into words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779700/lua-split-into-words)

```
s = "foo bar 123"
words = {}
for word in s:gmatch("%w+") do table.insert(words, word) end
```

And your code:

```
table.remove(words, 1)
```

Then your have your result:

```
> words[1]
bar
> words[2]
123
```

Edit: if you want to concatenate the remaining strings:

```
> words={"test", "123"}
> variable = table.concat(words, " ")
> variable
test 123
> type(variable)
string
>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but `get rid of the first word, but how can I save the rest as a variable`, you get rid of the first word with `remove`, and all the rest is saved in the variable `words`. What you want is concatenate the words in a string maybe?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the edit it solved my problem