# What is the neatest way to split out a Path Name into its components in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I have a standard Windows Filename with Path.  I need to split out the filename, extension and path from the string.

I am currently simply reading the string backwards from the end looking for . to cut off the extension, and the first \ to get the path.

I am sure I should be able to do this using a Lua pattern, but I keep failing when it comes to working from the right of the string.

eg.
c:\temp\test\myfile.txt
should return

- c:\temp\test\
- myfile.txt
- txt

Thank you in advance apologies if this is a duplicate, but I could find lots of examples for other languages, but not for Lua.

Comment: I'd argue just reading the string backwards is a better way to do it - pattern matching is overkill in this situation, will probably run 10x times slower and will take longer to grasp once you are in a maintenance state and have forgotten every detail of your code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
> return string.match([[c:\temp\test\myfile.txt]], "(.-)([^\\]-([^%.]+))$")
c:\temp\test\   myfile.txt  txt
```

This seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much,  you don't want to know how long I played with the match string,  I will work through your answer to learn how it works.

Comment: @Jane: the important things to note are the non-greedy `-`'s and their placement.

Answer (score 39):

Here is an improved version that works for Windows and Unix paths and also handles files without dots (or files with multiple dots):

```
= string.match([[/mnt/tmp/myfile.txt]], "(.-)([^\\/]-%.?([^%.\\/]*))$")
"/mnt/tmp/" "myfile.txt"    "txt"

= string.match([[/mnt/tmp/myfile.txt.1]], "(.-)([^\\/]-%.?([^%.\\/]*))$")
"/mnt/tmp/" "myfile.txt.1"  "1"

= string.match([[c:\temp\test\myfile.txt]], "(.-)([^\\/]-%.?([^%.\\/]*))$")
"c:\\temp\\test\\"  "myfile.txt"    "txt"

= string.match([[/test.i/directory.here/filename]], "(.-)([^\\/]-%.?([^%.\\/]*))$")
"/test.i/directory.here/"   "filename"  "filename"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Split string in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426954/split-string-in-lua)

There is a few string to table functions there, split "\" as \ cant be in a folder name anyway so you'll end up with a table with index one being the drive and the last index being the file.