# Break a string to table

Tags: string, lua, lua-table, lua-patterns, ptokax

Currently, I am using this function:

```
function tokenize( str )
  local ret = {}
  string.gsub( str, "([-%w%p()%[%]®+]+)", function( s ) table.insert( ret, s ) end )
  return ret
end
```

Now, the string can have any character in it(as is clear from function above). I want to break the string to words detecting only the white-spaces and no other character. I have seen the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426954/split-string-in-lua) but it is not helping me even on codepad.org ([link](http://codepad.org/PywG2zuI)). I am working in PtokaX, in case you are wondering. I have tried using

```
print( split( 'foo/bar/baz/test','/' ) )
```

too, but that doesn't work either. :(

Is there any other easier way to create the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just match for non space characters, instead of matching all others?

```
function tokenize( str )
  local ret = {}
  string.gsub( str, "(%S+)", function( s ) table.insert( ret, s ) end )
  return ret
end
```

If you want to use other characters for splitting, the pattern set negation is also useful:

```
s='foo#bar!baz*'
s:gsub('([^#!%*]+)',function(s) print(s) end)
```

See also: [Patterns in the Lua Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1).
Also keep in mind Lua patterns are not the same as regexes, they are lighter, but have their limitations.

Answer (score 1):

If you will be working with more advanced structures, I recommend [LPeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/).

```
require"lpeg"
lpeg.locale(lpeg)

local pattern = lpeg.P(
    lpeg.Ct(
        (lpeg.space^0*lpeg.C(-lpeg.space)^1)^0
    )
)

local ret = lpeg.match(pattern, str)

for k,v in ipairs(ret) do
    print(k, v)
end
```