# Split a string and store in an array in lua

Tags: string, lua, split

I need to split a string and store it in an array. here i used string.gmatch method, and its splitting the characters exactly, but my problem is how to store in an array ? here is my script. 
my sample string format : touchedSpriteName = Sprite,10,rose

```
objProp = {}
for key, value in string.gmatch(touchedSpriteName,"%w+") do 
objProp[key] = value
print ( objProp[2] )
end
```

if i print(objProp) its giving exact values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your expression returns only one value. Your words will end up in keys, and values will remain empty. You should rewrite the loop to iterate over one item, like this:

```
objProp = { }
touchedSpriteName = "touchedSpriteName = Sprite,10,rose"
index = 1

for value in string.gmatch(touchedSpriteName, "%w+") do 
    objProp[index] = value
    index = index + 1
end

print(objProp[2])
```

This prints `Sprite` ([link](http://ideone.com/EKZje) to demo on ideone).

Comment: hi dasblinkenlight, Thank you and just now get the same answer from this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426954/split-string-in-lua?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

Here's a nice function that explodes a string into an array. (Arguments are `divider` and `string`)

```
-- Source: http://lua-users.org/wiki/MakingLuaLikePhp
-- Credit: http://richard.warburton.it/
function explode(div,str)
    if (div=='') then return false end
    local pos,arr = 0,{}
    for st,sp in function() return string.find(str,div,pos,true) end do
        table.insert(arr,string.sub(str,pos,st-1))
        pos = sp + 1
    end
    table.insert(arr,string.sub(str,pos))
    return arr
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that i made:

```
function split(str, character)
  result = {}

  index = 1
  for s in string.gmatch(str, "[^"..character.."]+") do
    result[index] = s
    index = index + 1
  end

  return result
end
```

And you can call it :

```
split("dog,cat,rat", ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Reworked code of Ricardo:

```
local function  split (string, separator)
    local tabl = {}
    for str in string.gmatch(string, "[^"..separator.."]+") do
        table.insert (tabl, str)
    end
    return tabl
end

print (unpack(split ("1234#5678#9012", "#"))) 
-- returns  1234    5678    9012
```