# How to split string in Lua with comma

Tags: string, lua, split, coronasdk, lua-patterns

I need separated string with limited string(for me comma) or char in array. How separated o split with comma in Lua.

I check these links, but I don't understand:

http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin

http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426954/split-string-in-lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426954/splitstring-in-lua)

```
objPropo = {}
str = "Maria Mercedez,,Jose,Sofia"
i = 1
for token in string.gmatch(str, ",") do
    objPropo[i] = token
    i = i + 1
end
native.showAlert("Names", objPropo[1], {"OK"})
native.showAlert("Names", objPropo[2], {"OK"})  <-- Is this error? Because is nil? or what happend?
native.showAlert("Names", objPropo[3], {"OK"})
native.showAlert("Names", objPropo[4], {"OK"})
```

It could show:

```
Maria Mercedez
```

How formatt send patterns?

[Other alternative]

if is possible this?

```
objPropo = {}
str = "Maria Mercedez,,Jose,Sofia"
i = 1
for token in string.gmatch(str, ",") do
    objPropo[token] = token           <-------- CHECK
    i = i + 1
end
native.showAlert("Names", objPropo["Maria Mercedez"], {"OK"})
native.showAlert("Names", objPropo["Jose"], {"OK"})
```

Is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To split a string with commas, you need to use a pattern that matches non-commas (followed by a comma):

```
for token in string.gmatch(str, "([^,]+),%s*") do
    objPropo[i] = token
    i = i + 1
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I resolved this problem with:
string.gmatch(event.result, "[^,]+")

Comment: @Ryuchan That would include whitespaces before the names, if that's what you want.

Comment: No included whitespaces before the names. Now, I did edit. I want know what happen if between comma nothing character.