# Split string with specified delimiter in lua

Tags: regex, lua

I'm trying to create a split() function in lua with delimiter by choice, when the default is space.
the default is working fine. The problem starts when I give a delimiter to the function. For some reason it doesn't return the last sub string.
The function:

```
function split(str,sep)
if sep == nil then
    words = {}
    for word in str:gmatch("%w+") do table.insert(words, word) end
    return words
end
return {str:match((str:gsub("[^"..sep.."]*"..sep, "([^"..sep.."]*)"..sep)))} -- BUG!! doesnt return last value
end
```

I try to run this:

```
local str = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g"
local sep = ","
t = split(str,sep)
for i,j in ipairs(t) do
    print(i,j)
end
```

and I get:

```
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
6   f
```

Can't figure out where the bug is...

Comment: This is because you have not sep at the end of string. But pattern is `[^,]*,`. PS. For publicity https://github.com/moteus/lua-split.

Comment: See also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36957798/split-a-string-by-a-character-in-lua/36958689#36958689

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When splitting strings, the easiest way to avoid corner cases is to append the delimiter to the string, when you know the string cannot end with the delimiter:

```
str = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g"
str = str .. ','
for w in str:gmatch("(.-),") do print(w) end
```

Alternatively, you can use a pattern with an optional delimiter:

```
str = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g"
for w in str:gmatch("([^,]+),?") do print(w) end
```

Actually, we don't need the optional delimiter since we're capturing non-delimiters:

```
str = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g"
for w in str:gmatch("([^,]+)") do print(w) end
```

Comment: So simple and elegant... Thanks!

Comment: I think appending a delimiter to the string works in every case, not only when the string cannot end with a delimiter.  If the string ends with a delimiter, you will get an empty last match, which should be expected.

Comment: @tonypdmtr, sure, as long as you're clear about this, it's fine.

Comment: @lhf, why did you use `,?` in the end of the pattern? the result is the same with or without it.

Comment: This ought to be added to official Lua docs. There are way too many posts online that turn this simple question into a code golf inversion.

Answer (score 8):

Here's my go-to split() function:

```
-- split("a,b,c", ",") => {"a", "b", "c"}
function split(s, sep)
    local fields = {}
    
    local sep = sep or " "
    local pattern = string.format("([^%s]+)", sep)
    string.gsub(s, pattern, function(c) fields[#fields + 1] = c end)
    
    return fields
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`"[^"..sep.."]*"..sep` This is what causes the problem. You are matching a string of characters which are not the separator followed by the separator. However, the last substring you want to match (`g`) is not followed by the separator character.

The quickest way to fix this is to also consider `\0` a separator (`"[^"..sep.."\0]*"..sep`), as it represents the beginning and/or the end of the string. This way, `g`, which is not followed by a separator but by the end of the string would still be considered a match.

I'd say your approach is overly complicated in general; first of all you can just match individual substrings that do not contain the separator; secondly you can do this in a `for`-loop using the `gmatch` function

```
local result = {}
for field in your_string:gsub(("[^%s]+"):format(your_separator)) do
  table.insert(result, field)
end
return result
```

EDIT: The above code made a bit more simple:

```
local pattern = "[^%" .. your_separator .. "]+"
for field in string.gsub(your_string, pattern) do
-- ...and so on (The rest should be easy enough to understand)
```

EDIT2: Keep in mind that you should also escape your separators. A separator like `%` could cause problems if you don't escape it as `%%`

```
function escape(str)
  return str:gsub("([%^%$%(%)%%%.%[%]%*%+%-%?])", "%%%1")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I add a option for those who do not want to use Regex

```lua
local function split(str, sep)
  assert(type(str) == 'string' and type(sep) == 'string', 'The arguments must be <string>')
  if sep == '' then return {str} end
  
  local res, from = {}, 1
  repeat
    local pos = str:find(sep, from)
    res[#res + 1] = str:sub(from, pos and pos - 1)
    from = pos and pos + #sep
  until not from
  return res
end
```