# How do I split a string on a certain character in lua?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to split a string on a space in Lua. What I mean is if i had a string named "str" and it was equal to "hello world",

```
str = "hello world"
```

it should somehow return the string "world" because it is after the space. How do I do this?

Comment: Use `string.match` (https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.match). Lua library docs are really short. The only reason for not finding this info there would be not reading them at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1426954/1847592

Comment: Try it with the attached function ```sub``` In your case: ```print(str:sub(7))```

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi Wrong. `:sub` is not "splitting on a space" as question asked.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to take only the first value before the first space:

```lua
local result = str:match("%w+")

print(result)
```

if you want to collect each of the elements separated by space:

```lua
local tb = {}

for i in str:gmatch("%w+") do
    print(i) 
    table.insert(tb, i) -- in case you want to store each separate element in a table
end
```