# Extract words in Lua split by Unicode spaces and control characters

Tags: unicode, split, lua, match

I'm interested in a pure-Lua (i.e., no external Unicode library) solution to extracting the units of a string between certain Unicode control characters and spaces. The code points I would like to use as delimiters are:

0000-0020
007f-00a0
00ad
1680
2000-200a
2028-2029
202f
205f
3000

I know how to access the code points in a string, for example:

```
> for i,c in utf8.codes("é$ \tπ") do print(c) end
233
36
32
9
960
128515
```

but I am not sure how to "skip" the spaces and tabs and reconstitute the other codepoints into strings themselves. What I would like to do in the example above, is drop the 32 and 9, then perhaps use utf8.char(233, 36) and utf8.char(960, 128515) to somehow get ["é$", "π"].

It seems that putting everything into a table of numbers and painstakingly walking through the table with for-loops and if-statements would work, but is there a better way? I looked into string:gmatch but that seems to require making utf8 sequences out of each of the ranges I want, and it's not clear what that pattern would even look like.

Is there a idiomatic way to extract the strings between the spaces? Or must I manually hack tables of code points? `gmatch` does not look up to the task. Or is it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426954/split-string-in-lua)

Comment: Thanks, I did read that entire question (with so many great answers) and a lot of other Lua unicode questions on this site, but it seems that the pattern I need would require painstakingly generating the utf8 encodings for all code points at each end of the range. Or is there an answer in there that does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would require painstakingly generating the utf8 encodings for all code points at each end of the range.

Yes.  But of course not manually.

```
local function range(from, to)
   assert(utf8.codepoint(from) // 64 == utf8.codepoint(to) // 64)
   return from:sub(1,-2).."["..from:sub(-1).."-"..to:sub(-1).."]"
end

local function split_unicode(s)
   for w in s
      :gsub("[\0-\x1F\x7F]", " ")
      :gsub("\u{00a0}", " ")
      :gsub("\u{00ad}", " ")
      :gsub("\u{1680}", " ")
      :gsub(range("\u{2000}", "\u{200a}"), " ")
      :gsub(range("\u{2028}", "\u{2029}"), " ")
      :gsub("\u{202f}", " ")
      :gsub("\u{205f}", " ")
      :gsub("\u{3000}", " ")
      :gmatch"%S+"
   do
      print(w)
   end
end
```

Test:

```
split_unicode("@\0@\t@\x1F@\x7F@\u{00a0}@\u{00ad}@\u{1680}@\u{2000}@\u{2005}@\u{200a}@\u{2028}@\u{2029}@\u{202f}@\u{205f}@\u{3000}@")
```

Comment: Nice, TIL range()!