# Lua return end value in a string

Tags: string, lua

If I have this string: "wwww:xxxx:yyyy:zzzzzz:0"

How can I return only the "zzzzzz:0" value? Knowing that zzzzz will not always be the same length.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1) for this:

```
 string.match("wwww:xxxx:yyyy:zzzzzz:0", "[^:]+:[^:]+$")  --> 'zzzzzz:0'
```

This is naïve and focuses entirely on expressing this particular intent. `[^:]+` matches a sequence of one or more characters that are not `:`, `:` after that matches itself, and `$` matches the end of the string.

Based on the format of your string, you might want to look into splitting the string using `:` as a separator. This can be accomplished with e.g., [`string.gmatch`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.gmatch) and the `[^:]+` pattern from above. See [Split string in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426954/split-string-in-lua) for a detailed explanation of this problem.

In a complex situation where the components are expected to e.g., support quoting or escape sequences, and if you are highly concerned with time or memory optimisation you should look to use [a csv-like parser](https://luarocks.org/search?q=csv).

Comment: Pretty sure "naive" in this case means worst-case exponential runtime, so I'd definitely recommend going the `gmatch` route you have outlined if this ever sees user input.

Comment: @LMD, Yes, around 5 times worse in case of the example.

Answer (score 1):

Try also this somewhat simpler pattern:

```
string.match("wwww:xxxx:yyyy:zzzzzz:0", ".+:(.+:.+)$")
```

It looks for the last item of the form `foo:bar`.

Comment: Note that in this case the string _must have_ at least three component (which is a fair assumption in situations like this). Otherwise, one can e.g., prepend delimiting character to the string (in that case you only need to ensure two components, and that's even a better assumption since we're looking for the last two).