# Lua do something for each word

Tags: lua, scripting

Is there something to do something with each word like put them in a table but without it being a list. So like a full sentence (string) like this:

```
skylift valkyrie2 airbus hunter adder bus armytanker armytrailer armytrailer2 baletrailer boattrailer
```

```
do ... for each word
    (put in table)
end
```

Comment: use search on this site, [for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426954/split-string-in-lua)

Comment: "put them in a table but without it being a list" - so what do you want? a set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `gsub()`?

```
€ /bin/lua
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> str = "skylift valkyrie2 airbus hunter adder bus armytanker armytrailer armytrailer2 baletrailer boattrailer"
> do local text, count = str:gsub('%w+', function(match) return(match):upper() end) print(text, count) end
SKYLIFT VALKYRIE2 AIRBUS HUNTER ADDER BUS ARMYTANKER ARMYTRAILER ARMYTRAILER2 BALETRAILER BOATTRAILER   11
```

You are free to do what you want in the function in `gsub()`.
For example `table.insert(gstab, match)`

```
> gstab = {}
> gsfunc = function(match) local match = match:sub(1, 1):upper() .. match:sub(2, -1) table.insert(gstab, match) return(match) end
> str:gsub('%w+', gsfunc)
> print(table.concat(gstab, '\n'))
Skylift
Valkyrie2
Airbus
Hunter
Adder
Bus
Armytanker
Armytrailer
Armytrailer2
Baletrailer
Boattrailer
```