# Pandoc Lua filter wraps the space or the symbols with an element instead of wrapping the keys with an arrow element

Tags: html, lua, markdown, pandoc

Good evening,

I built a Pandoc Lua filter to convert the Markdown syntax code for the menukeys to HTML, inspired by the $\LaTeX$ package [`menukeys`](https://ctan.org/pkg/menukeys).

Here is an example of Markdown syntax code:

```
Path: `> C > Users > {usuario} > AppData > Roaming > nvm`
Path: `> Network & Internet > Wi-Fi > Hardware Properties`
```

It will become into HTML:

```html
<p> Path: 
   <span class="menukeys">
      <span class="menukey">C</span>
      <span class="menukey">Users</span>
      <span class="menukey">{usuario}</span>
      <span class="menukey">AppData</span>
      <span class="menukey">Roaming</span>
      <span class="menukey">nvm</span>
   </span>
</p>

<p> Path: 
   <span class="menukeys">
      <span class="menukey">Network & Internet</span>
      <span class="menukey">Wi-Fi</span>
      <span class="menukey">Hardware Properties</span>
   </span>
</p>
```

But only the second paragraph was wrongly converted due a space for the symbols or the sentence, because it became into:

```html
<p> Path: 
   <span class="menukeys">
      <span class="menukey">Network</span>
      <span class="menukey">&amp;</span>
      <span class="menukey">Internet</span>
      <span class="menukey">Wi-Fi</span>
      <span class="menukey">Hardware</span>
      <span class="menukey">Properties</span>
   </span>
</p>
```

It looked like:

[image: Before]

It should look like:

[image: After]

Follow the follow Pandoc Lua filter code:

```lua
function string:split(separator)
  local fields = {}
  local pattern = string.format("([^%s]+)", separator)
  self:gsub(pattern, function(c) fields[#fields + 1] = c end)
  return fields
end

function Code(elem)
  if elem.text:sub(1, 1) == ">" then
    local parts = elen.text:sub(2):split(" > ")
    local newContent = ""
    
    for i, part in ipairs(parts) do
      newContent = newContent .. 'span class="menukey">' .. part .. '</span>'
    end

    newContent = '<span class="menukeys">' .. newContent .. '</span>'

    return pandoc.RawInline('html', newContent)
  end
end
```

Comment: looks like your `string:split` function not only splits at the `separator`, but also at any whitespace? I'd try a different split function, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426954/split-string-in-lua

Comment: Replace `split(" > ")` with `split(">")`