Lua string.gmatch find empty fields between separators
I'm currently trying to convert a string into a table via separators. The separating itself works perfectly fine. In my example, I have two different separators. A ';' which leaves a string separated via ','.
In the optimal case, my data looks like this, after the first separation has been run through.
{'xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx'}
However, the form that is providing the data, has some fields as optional, which leaves the data I receive like this:
{'xxxx,,xxxx,,xxxx'} -- there were two optional fields which leaves me with two separators right next to each other.
With the following function, I tried to accomplish this and fill fields with no content between separators with a '-'. However this doesn't work. Then Lua detects the separators and empty spaces, but also when there's only one ',' for example.
This problem shouldn't be something rare, yet I seem to have been unable to find anything that helps me.
  local tbl = {}

  if sep1 == nil then
    sep1 = "%s"
  end

  for str in string.gmatch(inputstr, "([^"..sep1.."]+)") do
    table.insert(tbl, str)
  end

  if sep2 then
    for i, v in ipairs(tbl) do
      local tbl2 = {}
      
      local matches = 0;
      
-- my attempt to check if it's a double ',', this fails however
      for str in string.gmatch(v, "([^"..sep2.."]*)") do
        if str == '' then
          matches = matches + 1
          
          if str == '' and matches == 1 then
            str = '-'
            matches = 0;
          end
        
        end
                
        if (str ~= '' and  str ~= nil) then
          table.insert(tbl2, str)
        end

      end
      tbl[i] = tbl2
    end
  end
  
  return tbl  
  
end


Please try the https://stackoverflow.com/a/1647577/12968803 Is it good for you?

Thank you for you answer. The description seems like it's what I'm looking for. However, I fail to understand how it works or how I even integrate it. I can see a getter function, which I've read about in OOP, but none of it makes sense to me. Is there something specific I could read about to be able to understand the given example a bit  better?

@milk - The official Lua tutorial (the book "Programming in Lua" by Roberto, first edition is free) is enough to understand the code in that answer.
