Detect text block between two tags
I have a file structured like this
$$ some text $$
and I would like to make my script reveal when there is a block of text present within the "$$" tags. This script works well when the text is of the form $$ some text $$
function file_exists(name)
    local f = io.open(name, "r")
    if f ~= nil then
        io.close(f)
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

function rows_from(file)
    if not file_exists(file) then
        return {}
    end
    local rows = {}
    for line in io.lines(file) do
        rows[#rows + 1] = line
    end
    return rows
end

function detect_non_indexed_equations(rows,j)
    if rows[j]:sub(1,2) == "$$" then
        for i=j, #rows do
            if rows[i]:sub(-2) == "$$" then
                print("text between $$ detected")
                break
            end
        end
    end
end

function fetch_equations(start)
    local rows = rows_from(file)
    for j = start, #rows do
        detect_non_indexed_equations(rows,j)
    end
end

fetch_equations(1)

But the block is written like
$$
    some text
$$

print("text between $$ detected") run twice, and the block is not revealed correctly.
Any ideas?

Without digging too deep, I believe that this algorithm works with separate lines rather than complete text, and that is why lines with '$$' only trigger both conditions starts with '$$' and ends with '$$'.

I would suggest rewriting this just as a simple file_contents:gmatch"%$%$(.-)%$%$"; it isn't yet clear to me whether you need $$ to be at the start / end of a line though.

@Luatic yes, I need $$ to be at start/end of a line. $$ is a LaTeX tag to display math equations, just like, for example,   in XML.

You could do this by splitting the string on $$ occurrences.
Given the input of something like
Some text
$$ Something else $$
Some more text
$$
Another example
$$
end

local inputStr = [[Some text
$$ Inside area $$
Some more text
$$
Another
$$
end]]

-- Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426954/split-string-in-lua
function splitString(inputstr, sep)
  if sep == nil then
    sep = "%s"
  end
  local t = {}
  for str in string.gmatch(inputstr, "([^"..sep.."]+)") do
    table.insert(t, str)
  end
  return t
end

local stringParts = splitString(inputStr, "$$")

for i, v in ipairs(stringParts) do
  if i % 2 == 0 then
    -- When i is a multiple of 2 its inside the $$ tags, supports multi line
    print("$$ area detected", i, v)
  end
end

The above code splits the input string into an array on the $$ tags, if the current index is even we are between $$ tags, if it is odd then we are in normal text.
This doesn't cover the case of the $$ being at the start or end of a line, but that should be relatively trivial to implement. If the index is even you can just check the previous segment to see if it ended in a new line and check if the next segment starts with a new line.

Thank you! The only problem is that these strings are file lines, so the multiline string you reported must be created by reading some file section line by line.

You could still use a similar approach to the above, for each line split on the $$ and keep track of how many elements in the array. Have a global counter somewhere, if a line has more than 1 parts iterate over it and increment the global counter by one for each part the current line array has
